# How to remove the auto added column (HeaderRole=Padding) in WPF GridView

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridview

I'm trying to make a custom gridview in WPF but I just realized that as this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumnheader.role.aspx) says:

> The GridViewHeaderRowPresenter class
>   performs layout for the column headers
>   in a GridView and places an additional
>   column header at the end to add space

and because of the additional column header at the end, there's an extra column to the right of the last column. so I was wondering if I can modify it, please refer to this image below [image]

My questions are:

2. Is there anyway I can remove the 'A' part from the grid?
3. Is there anyway I can add the same effect of 'B' part (the role = padding header) to the 'C' Part (before the first column)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After poking around a lot I managed to hide this extra column just by setting negative margin in a few places. It's quite hacky but it works:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,-7,1"/>
</Style>

 <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,-2,0"/>
</Style>
```

And perhaps add

```
<Trigger Property="Role" Value="Padding">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
</Trigger>
```

in the GridViewColumnHeader style, as well.

First one can be set as negative as you like, it seems; it caps when it can't reduce anymore. Doing so will still leave a wee 2px gap on the right side of the headers, which the 2nd Style fixes.

Alas, the -2 margin applies to all GridViewColumnHeaders (and the Style Trigger method doesn't seem to work), so it can mess with inner borders and content alignment a bit, but if that's tolerable this works fine.

EDIT: Actually yeah scratch the -2 margin, it has too many negative side effects.

Inside `<Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">` you'll find a `<GridViewHeaderRowPresenter>`; set its Margin equal to `"0,0,-2,0"` and you'll get the same effect without the drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the first column "C" you can add the following property to your DataGrid definition:

```
RowHeaderWidth="0"
```