# Additional column in GridView

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, datagrid

I use a List to populate a WPF `GridView` as its `ItemsSource`. This is the xaml markup I use:

```
<ListView.View>
  <GridView>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Subject" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Subject}" />
    <GridViewColumn Header="Start" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=StartingDate}" />
    <GridViewColumn Header="End" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=EndingDate}" />
    <GridViewColumn Header="Commissioner" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Commissioner}" />
    <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=QuickNotes}" />
  </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Surprisingly (at least for me), I get an additional (empty) column as shown below. What important point am I missing?
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not an "actual" column, it's more like empty space next to the last column.

Comment: How come the empty space is resizable then? Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: You are not resizing the space, you are resizing the last column. Not sure if anything can be done about it...

Comment: @fjdumont increase the Size of the Remaining columns, so that the Last column will not appear.

Comment: @fjdumont: There already is [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553073/how-to-remove-the-auto-added-column-headerrole-padding-in-wpf-gridview) about removing that column but its unanswere.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use a DataGrid instead of the ListView. Then you can set one of the Columns to have a Width of * which will cause it to take up all remaining space. Sadly you can't set a width of * on GridView columns.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Subject" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="End" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Commissioner" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Also DataGrids look kinda ungly by default if you compare them to a ListView.

Comment: True - I but you can always style them however you want - plus it gives a good alternative.

Comment: And it's only available starting from .NET 4.